# Prepend StackName to Cloudformation resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, naming

I want to have multiple stacks based on a single CloudFormation template, but I'm getting naming conflicts. The simplest way to resolve this would seem to be prepending (or appending) the `StackName` to each of the repeated resources, e.g. my lambda functions or roles.

AWS talks about `AWS::StackName` in the ['Template Reference' section of the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-stackname), but there's no clear demonstration of how to do this.

How can I prepend the `StackName` to a CloudFormation resource?

```
MyLambdaFunction
  Type: "AWS:Serverless::Function"
  Properties:
    FunctionName: AWS::StackName + "-myLambdaFunction"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `Ref` the pseudoparameter and use the `Fn::Join` method to construct the name

```
MyLambdaFunction
  Type: "AWS:Serverless::Function"
  Properties:
    FunctionName: !Join [ "", [ {"Ref": "AWS::StackName"}, "-myLambdaFunction" ]]
```

Answer (score 8):

I prefer using [Fn::Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html), because I believe that it's easier to read than the alternatives:

```
"RoleName": { "Fn::Sub" : "${AWS::StackName}-InstanceRole" },
```

Comment: Needs more upvotes. Even in YAML templates, Join can be an unreadable mess, while Sub is just so straightforward. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

The YAML version:

```
RoleName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-InstanceRole
```